# Python 3 int() function is not converting input string to integer

Tags: python, int

I am working on a small program that reads data from a CSV file. As part of the program, user input is used to only select data that >= but I get **TypeError: unorderable types: str() >= int()** when I run the code. Looks like the sting is not converting to integer.

```
def get_csv_data(data_type, num):
    import csv
    ga_session_data = {}
    ga_pageviews_data = {}

    with open('files/data.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in reader:
            page, sessions, pageviews = row
            ga_session_data[page] = int(sessions)
            ga_pageviews_data[page] = int(pageviews)

        if data_type == 'sessions' and sessions >= int(num):
            for page, sessions in ga_session_data.items():
                print(page, ' - ', sessions)

        elif data_type == 'pageviews' and pageviews >= int(num):
            for page, pageviews in ga_pageviews_data.items():
                print(page, ' - ', pageviews)

def main():
    while(True):
        question = input("Are you interested in sessions or pageviews?")

        if question == 'sessions':
            number = int(input("What range are you interested in?"))
            get_csv_data(data_type = 'sessions', num = int(number))

        elif question == 'pageviews':
            number = input("What range are you interested in?")
            get_csv_data(data_type = 'pageviews', num = int(number))

        else:
            print("Invalid Input. Choose between sessions and pageviews.")
main()
```

Comment: In `sessions >= int(num)`, you're comparing a string (`sessions`) with an int.

Comment: same is true for pageviews >= int(num)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`int` does not *cast* its parameters to integer in-place. In fact those parameters are immutable.

`int(sessions)` does not *exactly* do what you think it does. `session` is not modified, but the return value of that call is an `int`.

You should assign the returned value to a new/same name:

```
sessions = int(sessions)
pageviews = int(pageviews)
```

The operator `>=` can now compare the two variables you have, since they are now both integers.

---

You may also want to rewrite that `if` block like so:

```
if data_type == 'sessions':
     for page, sessions in ga_session_data.items():
         if sessions >= int(num):
             print(page, ' - ', sessions)
```

In this way, you're actually checking the sessions count in the dictionary and not the sessions from the for loop.

Comment: Thanks. I changed it and the error went away but for some reason nothing gets returned after I input the number

Comment: @user3088202 But you are not *returning* anything in your function?

Comment: Sorry just started learning Python. Are you talking about main function or get_csv_data

Comment: `get_csv_data`. What output were you expecting?

Comment: page name and number of sessions/pageviews.  Basicly, pull all page names and sessions where sessions total is >= some number

Comment: You mean nothing gets printed? I think you want to run the check on the sessions in the dictionary. Give me a few minutes to write a fix for you

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118566/discussion-between-moses-koledoye-and-user3088202).